# SSE (Intel) to NEON (ARM) data type analogs

Tags: ios, arm, vectorization, sse, neon

I have a few intrinsic datatypes `__m128`, `__m128i` that have either been on the left side of the assignment OR as parameters. I am in the process of converting the SSE code to NEON (for deployment on iOS) but I am unable to find the analogous data types for these (and other) SSE datatypes.

(References and links pointing to relevant material will be greatly appreciated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they were simple movs, data types don't matter; Assigning quad vectors will do.

And If not, NEON dosen't support any kind of 128bit data. No luck here.

Comment: So I could basically use `float32x4_t` for `__m128`?

Comment: Likely. If you are just transferring 128bit data around, any data type will do.